# How to read the real time changes in a file with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, file-io, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to let my CasperJS script read an outside txt file (abc.txt), and the abc.txt needed to be created in the middle of the CasperJS process.

(and that abc.txt has to be create using 'curl' for some third party api, so I called a childprocess to renew the old abc.txt).

However, the information inside abc.txt seems locked at the begging, it doesn't matter whether I changed the information or delete the whole file.

Has anyone any idea if CasperJS can be more interactive?
or any advice if I need to change the whole script?

(I am trying to get a question from websiteA, then go to websiteB find the answer, then submit the answer in websiteA)

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.read('abc.txt');

casper.start();

casper.wait(5000, function () {
  console.log('wait 5000 for editing the file');
});

casper.then(function (){
  console.log(data);
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: You can read it again when you've changed the content. I don't know of any language where there is a direct binding between a string and the contents of a file.

Comment: yes..i made a console log  between and after the change of that text file, but the result has no different...i have seen your post teaching people passing the captchas. have you encountered any problem yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of data.txt changes, during the execution of your script, this doesn't have any influence on variables that hold a copy of the content of that file. There is never a direct connection between the string value and the file content.

If you want to refresh the string content, you need to read that file again:

```
data = fs.read('abc.txt');
```

If you need to wait for the change of the file, then you can periodically read the file contents to see if they changed in the mean time. This can be done with [`casper.waitFor()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.read('abc.txt');
var newData;

casper.start();
casper.waitFor(function _check(){
    newData = fs.read('abc.txt');
    return data !== newData;
});
casper.wait(1000); // additional wait to make sure that the file writing has finished
casper.then(function (){
    console.log(newData);
});
casper.run();
```

Comment: Hi Professor Artjom B. thanks for the help. But i am running into another question regards to casper clicking. please take a look at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624424/how-do-casperjs-click-on-some-unidentify-button"  thanks so much!!